# Erro na implementação Calculadora webService

Tags: java, android

Estou montando uma calculadora igual ao livro do Ricardo Lecheta para entendimento de webservice, porém estou com 2 erros ocasionado por uma má conversão do `DataInputStream` nos valores que deveriam ser recebidos, acontecendo o seguinte erro:

> *Error:(24, 32) error: constructor Calculadora in class Calculadora cannot be applied to given types; required: String,int found:
>   DataInputStream reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in
>   length*

gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado

minha classe Principal

```
   public class CalculadoraSocket extends Activity {

   private static final int PORTA = 7777;
   public static  void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORTA);
    System.out.println("Socket Aberto na porta 7777");
    while(true){

        System.out.println("esperando....");
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Conectou");
        new CalculadoraSocketThread(socket).start();



        }
    }
}
```

Classe que recebe a thread que está dando problema de conversão

```
 public class CalculadoraSocketThread extends  Thread {
 private final Socket socket;


public CalculadoraSocketThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run(){
    try {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Calculadora calc = new Calculadora(in);
        calc.somar();
        calc.enviar(out);
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}// fim run


}
```

// os metodos de somar na calculadora pelo webservice

```
  public  Calculadora(String ip, int porta) throws IOException{
      socket = new Socket(ip,porta);
      out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    Log.i(CATEGORIA, "Conexao Realizada com sucesso! ");
}// fim calculadora


     public int somar (int n1, int n2) throws IOException{
    try{
        Log.i(CATEGORIA, "Enviando numeros"+n1+" e  "+n2);

        out.writeInt(n1);
        out.writeInt(n2);

        out.flush();
        Log.i(CATEGORIA,"Lendo resposta");

        soma = in.readInt();
        Log.i(CATEGORIA,"Soma:   "+soma);
        return soma;

    }finally {
        close();
    }


}

public void close() throws IOException{

    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();

}
public void enviar(DataOutputStream out) throws  IOException{

    //envia a soma pro service

    out.writeInt(soma);

}// fim enviar
```

// implementação do exemplo

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText txtn1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.n1);
    EditText txtn2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.n2);
    TextView txtSoma = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soma);
    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(txtn1.getText().toString());
    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(txtn2.getText().toString());
    try{
        Calculadora calculadora = new Calculadora(IP,PORTA);
        int soma = calculadora.somar(n1,n2);
        String txtsoma = "Soma: "+soma;
        txtSoma.setText(txtsoma);
        Log.i(CATEGORIA,String.valueOf(txtsoma));
        txtSoma.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    } catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(CATEGORIA, e.getMessage(),e);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente você está tentando usar um construtor da classe **Calculadora** que recebe um **DataInputStream**, mas o Java diz que o construtor esperava uma **String** e um **int**. O Java não encontrou o construtor que você queria usar.

> Error:(24, 32) error: constructor Calculadora in class Calculadora
>   cannot be applied to given types; **required: String,int found:
>   DataInputStream** reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in
>   length

No seu código você faz  isso:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Calculadora calc = new Calculadora(in);
```

E seu construtor é esse:

```
public  Calculadora(String ip, int porta) throws IOException{
      socket = new Socket(ip,porta);
      out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    Log.i(CATEGORIA, "Conexao Realizada com sucesso! ");
}// fim calculadora
```

Comment: sim mas o DataInputStream é pra ler os dados primitivos, como o parametro da calculadora são 2 dados primitivos(string e int) o DataInputStream deveria receber esses valores não?

Comment: pelo que li nao preciso do IP, e porta, posso passar o parametro como in ali mesmo e nao preciso declarar dentro


          public  Calculadora(DataInputStream in)

 ficaria assim e la dentro do soma eu recebo n1 e n2 que sao os valores de soma

           n1 = in.readInt();
           n2 = in.readInt();

Comment: Correto, precisa usar o método in.readInt() para ler os valores recebidos (no caso int). Acredito que fazendo essas correções no construtor da Calculadora vai resolver seu problema